# Strange vagrant shared folder issue -> can not "rm -rf"

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, ubuntu-14.04, shared-directory

My Vagrantfile:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

    config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
      v.name = "web_vm"
      v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", "1024"]
      #v.customize ["setextradata", :id, "VBoxInternal2/SharedFoldersEnableSymlinksCreate/web_vm", "1"]
    end

  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
  config.vm.network :forwarded_port, host: 81, guest: 80, auto_correct: true
  config.vm.network :forwarded_port, host: 6612, guest: 3306, auto_correct: true
  config.vm.synced_folder "src/", "/var/www", owner: "vagrant", group: "vagrant", :mount_options => ["dmode=777,fmode=777"]
  config.vm.provision :shell, path: "bootstrap.sh"
end
```

As you can see, The "src" folder is accessible in vagrant as "/var/www". However, there seem to be sync problems: I am trying to remove a folder which is shown empty where it is not when you cross-check with the Windows Explorer.

Any idea what is happening here?

[image: Shared folder contents not conmpletely listed with ls]

Comment: so how about `sudo rm -rf ...`?

Comment: same result, the folder already belongs to `vagrant` so there is no difference.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, but it seemed to be resolved by increasing the max_user_watches - variable for inotify:

```
echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf && sudo sysctl -p
```

My guess was that this had to to with the amount of files in the shared folder, and how vagrant has implemented the shared folder functionality.